# Only positive number expression label in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

I was just wondering if anybody knows of a way to write an expression to make all my numeric values in my labels positive.

I want to do 1234 cal BC 23 cal AD for example, as a label.

My data is - 1234 (being BC) and 23 for AD.

any ideas?

Comment: For quick draw time, add/calculate a new field of all positive values with the designated BC or AD already in it.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the **Labels** tab on Layer Properties, click **Expression...**.
On the **Label Expression** dialog

1. check the **Advanced** checkbox
2. paste the code below into the **Expression** (update [DATE] to whatever your field name is)
3. set the **Parser** to python

.

```
def FindLabel ( [DATE] ):
  v = int([DATE])
  if v < 0:
    return "{} BC".format(abs(v))
  else:
    return [DATE] + " AD"
```

Then draw the Labels.

Answer (score 2):

On the 'Labels' page of the layer properties box (the one that opens when you double click a layer) you can use the Method drop down to define classes with different types of labels.

Then you can pick the features that have negative values and format their labels to be positive, then set up a second class to do the non-negative ones.

[This tutorial is much more detailed and goes through the whole process of creating label classes.](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/tutorials/bgdb/BGDB_Ex_6_1.htm)